# I want to know how to type a word from the clipboard and press enter in the file open window using c# and selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, clipboard, textinput, fileopendialog

I am a beginner programmer making programs using c# and selenium.
I want to know how to type a word from the clipboard and press enter in the file open window using c# and selenium.

I don't know what element to find the file open window.

[image]

Comment: There should be a duplicate on this site some place. This is a common question, but honestly I couldn't find one in a quick search. Can you show a representative snippet of the HTML Selenium is interacting with? I can for sure tell you that Selenium cannot do anything with the "Choose File" dialog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automating File Upload with Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107292/automating-file-upload-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: no.  I want to automatically paste the contents of the clipboard to the place where I put the file name and send enter.

Comment: Ok. Honestly it partially answers your question, though. You need to use `IWebElement.SendKeys(string)` to set the value. The trick is to paste from the clip board.

Comment: You will need to [edit] your question to include the HTML you are working with, otherwise we cannot answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I will do my best to solve this problem.